# Dimension too large error in marking of a Hobby curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby

I encountered a weird error when playing with Hobby curves and markings. Consider the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings,hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[use Hobby shortcut,decorate,decoration={markings, 
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.3pt with }] (1,0.00001)..(1.2685,0.00001);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It throws `Dimension too large` error. However, increasing the value of 1.2685 by a tiny bit (to 1.269 or more) makes the error disappear, but substituting it with 1.26855 makes the same error pop up twice. To make it even more interesting, having `(2,0.00001)..(2.2685,0.00001)` instead of `(1,0.00001)..(1.2685,0.00001)` is fine, but `(2,0.00001)..(2.2,0.00001)` throws an error again.

Change both 0.00001 to 0 makes and the error vanishes again. Variation of 0.3pt value seems not to influence the occurrence of the error.

What is happening here? What is the origin of the threshold value of 1.2685 and why does this threshold change when we shift everything by (0,1)? And, most importantly, can this error actually result in mistakes in the generated PDF? In my more sophisticated documents with this type of issue I've never noticed any impact of this `Dimension too large` error on the PDF which puzzles me even more. I used Overleaf if this matters.

Comment: Just to note: this is nothing to do with `hobby`.  It's because you are placing markings at very small intervals along a bezier curve.  If you take out the `decorate` then there is no error.  If you replace the hobby curve with a bezier then there is an error: `\draw[decorate,decoration={markings, 
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.3pt with }] (1,0.00001) .. controls +(.0895,0) and +(-.0895,0) .. (1.2685,0.00001);` gives an error.  If you replace the bezier with a straight line then there is no error.

Comment: See Qrrbrbirlbel's answer to this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699943/add-a-non-straight-path-with-tikz/700032#700032 (`fpu library`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With tkz-euclide, this error comes from using `veclen` with too small values. In my case the error comes from `decoration`. I don't know if `veclen` is the only function that produces this error.

To solve this problem I use an option (Schrodinger's cat idea) which I use with a scope to limit its action (waste of time). The idea is to temporarily perform the calculation of `veclen` by `xfp`. We could use `lua` too.

The only problem is that I never use `hobby` so I don't know and if there are no more errors, I get no results.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings,hobby}
\makeatletter
% Schrodinger's cat idea 03/01/20
\tikzset{xfp/.code={%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
    \pgfmath@x##1pt\relax%
    \pgfmath@y##2pt\relax%
    \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt((\pgf@x)^2+(\pgf@y)^2)}}
    \pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
}}}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xfp]
  \draw[use Hobby shortcut,decorate,decoration={markings, 
  mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.3pt with {.} }] (1,0.00001)..(1.2685,0.00001);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```