# Add a non-straight path with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Vertice con 5 archi
  \node[circle, draw] (v) at (0,0) {V};
  
  % Archi tratteggiati
  \draw (v.45) -- ++(45:1);
  \draw (v.90) -- ++(90:1);
  \draw (v.135) -- ++(135:1);
  \draw (v.180) -- ++(180:1);
  \draw (v.225) -- ++(225:1);
  \draw[dashed] (v.45) -- ++(45:2);
  \draw[dashed] (v.90) -- ++(90:2);
  \draw[dashed] (v.135) -- ++(135:2);
  \draw[dashed] (v.180) -- ++(180:2);
  \draw[dashed] (v.225) -- ++(225:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

draws the following picture

[image]

I would like to add a non-straight path, in a different color, that enters one line and exits in another, similar to the one depicted in the following figure (manually modified by me):

[image]

How can I obtain this result?

Comment: At the end of each dashed line add a coordinate to save the endpoint of the line, say `coordinate (p1)` and then you can use these coordinates to draw any paths between them. You might be interested in the `random steps` decoration of the [`decorations.pathmorphing` library](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf.decorations.pathmorphing) but that won't add loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With patience, using Luc Cholet's `Geogebra` file https://www.geogebra.org/m/RwNHMPk9, we can create Bézier curves.

- To make it easier to position points p1 and p2 in Geogebra, we set `minimum width=1cm` for the node containing V
- In Geogebra, we redefine the coordinates of point A by typing in the input field `A=(2.5; 45°)`

[image]

- We can use the + button to add one control point at a time.

[image]

- And finally with the tikz button copy then paste into the tex file

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Vertice con 5 archi
  \node[circle, draw,minimum width=1cm] (v) at (0,0) {V};%<-- modif
  % Archi tratteggiati
  \draw (v.45) -- ++(45:1);
  \draw (v.90) -- ++(90:1);
  \draw (v.135) -- ++(135:1);
  \draw (v.180) -- ++(180:1);
  \draw (v.225) -- ++(225:1);
  \draw[dashed] (v.45) -- ++(45:2)coordinate(p1);
  \draw[dashed] (v.90) -- ++(90:2)coordinate(p2);
  \draw[dashed] (v.135) -- ++(135:2);
  \draw[dashed] (v.180) -- ++(180:2);
  \draw[dashed] (v.225) -- ++(225:2);
  %
  \draw [green](p1)%<-- mdif after copy
  % \draw (1.7677669529663689,1.7677669529663687) 
  .. controls (3.1070703811315195,3.165645932288138 ) and (1.7281913375772981,2.434840039204401 ) .. (1.5696202475685628,2.2693745539778947)
  .. controls (1.4110491575598274,2.1039090687513884 ) and (1.2111116962444652,2.579622338777594 ) .. (1.5075706906086228,2.620988710084221)
  .. controls (1.8040296849727804,2.6623550813908476 ) and (1.245583672333321,3.1242795609815115 ) .. (0.9767022588402476,2.5865167339953654)
  .. controls (0.7078208453471744,2.0487539070092193 ) and (0.5,3.5 ) .. 
  % (0,2.5);
  (p2);%<-- mdif after copy
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Combining a few libraries …

- `arrows.meta` and `bending` for customizable and flexible/bendable arrow tips,
- `decorations.markings` for placing arrow tips along a path,
- `ext.arrows` from my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) for the `Centered Straight Barb` arrow tip,
- `fpu` for a more [precise `veclen`](https://tikz.dev/library-fpu#pgf./pgf/fpu/install:only) function that will fix some `Dimension too large` error that will come up with some Bézier curves,
- `hobby` for an alternative to the `smooth` plothandler that constructs a curve through coordinates and
- `math` to allow for a simple interface to on-the-fly calculations.

The latter is used to *not* use a random coordinate but the end point of the dashed lines.

Both `hobby` and the [`smooth` plothandler](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots#pgf./tikz/smooth) allow for customization of the underlying algorithm to construct a curve through the given points.

The default outputs are shown below.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,          % customizable arrow tips
  bending,              % flexed and bended arrow tips
  decorations.markings, % place arrow tips along any path
  ext.arrows,           % Centered Straight Barb
  fpu,                  % more precise veclen function for decoration along curve
  hobby,                % nicer (?) curves through points
  math}                 % on-the-fly calculations
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick, arrows={[round, scale=.5]},
  >      ={         Straight Barb[flex']}, % arrow tip for the end
  >'/.tip={Centered Straight Barb[quick]}] % arrow tip for along the path
\pgfmathsetseed{699943}
\node[circle, draw] (v) at (0,0) {V};
\foreach[count=\i from 0] \ang in {45, 90, ..., 225}
  \path (v.\ang) edge coordinate[at end](v'\i)  (\ang:1)
        (v'\i)   edge[dash pattern=on 1.3333mm off 1mm]
                      coordinate[at end](v''\i) (\ang:2);
\draw[
  cyan, <-, thin, /pgf/fpu/install only=veclen,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={
    name=markings,
    mark=between positions .125 and .875 step .125 with \arrowreversed{>'}
  }
] plot[smooth, samples at={0, ..., 40}]
  ([evaluate={
      coordinate \p; int \i;
      if mod(\x,10) == 0 then {
        \i = int(\x/10);
        \p = (v''\i);
      } else {
        \p = ({45+\x/40*180+rand}:{2+rand*.2});
      };}, shift={(\p)}]0pt,0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick, arrows={[round, scale=.5]},
  >      ={         Straight Barb[flex']}, % arrow tip for the end
  >'/.tip={Centered Straight Barb[quick]}] % arrow tip for along the path
\pgfmathsetseed{699943}
\node[circle, draw] (v) at (0,0) {V};
\foreach[count=\i from 0] \ang in {45, 90, ..., 225}
  \path (v.\ang) edge coordinate[at end](v'\i)  (\ang:1)
        (v'\i)   edge[dash pattern=on 1.3333mm off 1mm]
                      coordinate[at end](v''\i) (\ang:2);
\draw[
  cyan, <-, thin, /pgf/fpu/install only=veclen,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={
    name=markings,
    mark=between positions .125 and .875 step .125 with \arrowreversed{>'}
  }
] plot[hobby, samples at={0, ..., 40}]
  ([evaluate={
      coordinate \p; int \i;
      if mod(\x,10) == 0 then {
        \i = int(\x/10);
        \p = (v''\i);
      } else {
        \p = ({45+\x/40*180+rand}:{2+rand*.2});
      };}, shift={(\p)}]0pt,0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Everything after the node should be done under `shift=(v)` to make this work if the node isn't at the center.

Comment: With this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630349/dimension-too-large-error-in-marking-of-a-hobby-curve, I tested with Alain Matthes' answer, and it there is no longer a dimension too large when we change the `\pgfmathsetseed`

Comment: @pascal974 Indeed, the standard `veclen` function seems to be the problem. I have used the `fpu` library with a selective activation for the `veclen` function for these paths. The `\pgfmathsetseed` was mainly to have a consistent output but with my updated answer it also allows to easily compare `smooth` and `hobby`.