# dimension too large when using TikZ markings of rotated ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf

When [compiling](https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%5Btikz%5D%7Bstandalone%7D%0A%5Cusetikzlibrary%7Bdecorations.markings%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Btikzpicture%7D%5Byscale=cos(65)%5D%0A%5Cdraw%5Bpostaction=%7Bdecorate%7D,decoration=%7Bmarkings,mark=at%20position%200.5%20with%20%7B%5Carrow%7B%3E%7D%7D%7D,rotate%20around=%7B-10:(.9,-.5)%7D%5D(.9,-.5)circle(1.5mm%20and%203mm);%0A%5Cend%7Btikzpicture%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=cos(65)]
\draw[postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},rotate around={-10:(.9,-.5)}](.9,-.5)circle(1.5mm and 3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX throws error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.5 ...10:(.9,-.5)}](.9,-.5)circle(1.5mm and 3mm);
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.5 ...10:(.9,-.5)}](.9,-.5)circle(1.5mm and 3mm);
                                                  
End of file on the terminal!
```

This is a small and bounded figure. I wonder why "dimension is too large".

It works if changing the ellipse center to (0,0)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=cos(65)]
\draw[postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},rotate around={-10:(.9,-.5)}](0,0)circle(1.5mm and 3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Image: [image]

Enlarged: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the Qrrbrbirlbel's answer to this post [Add a non-straight path with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699943/add-a-non-straight-path-with-tikz/700032#700032)

With the `fpu` library.

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,fpu}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=cos(65)]
    \draw[
        /pgf/fpu/install only=veclen,
        postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        rotate around={-10:(.9,-.5)}
        ](.9,-.5)circle(1.5mm and 3mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```