# TikZ DECORATE incorrectly fails with "Dimension too large." using MiKTeX and TeX Live 2022

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here I document a problem that baffles me. I am using Ti*k*Z Decorate to position text along a gently sloping curve. There is ample room for the text and I use only a few coordinates as high precision for decorated text is unnecessary.

It works perfectly 99.9% of the time. I now have an `! Dimension too large.` error which I maintain is erroneous and I will explain why. The error is *purely data dependent* and thus I plead the case that it needs to be investigated. Here I include several `.tex` files: those that work error-free and one that fails. Henri Menke once commented here

> Decorations and smoothed paths don't play nicely.

whatever that means. I maintain that what I am doing should work 100% of the time ... meaning I see no reason why Ti*k*Z should not be able to position a simple line of text on a gentle curve as in my case (from an end-user perspective).

I create PDF charts and I have tested this on Windows 10 using the latest MiKTeX 23.10.12 and using Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS with Tex Live 2022 on identical hardware (thanks to a dual boot system) that is AMD-based. I also tested this on an old Windows 10 laptop with an i7-6700HQ CPU. I am therefore confident that you will be able to reproduce this error using the supplied `.tex` files I append below.

The chart for latitude 62.0°N fails. If **the data is changed very slightly**, the charts for 61.9°N and 62.1°N work perfectly. Furthermore, if I employ 4 decimal places instead of 3, the chart for 62.0°N then also works! The decorate code section for 62.0°N that **fails** is the following (beginning at line 1022 in the .tex file):

```
% decorate PM dusk with text aligned left
\path [decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=-2.4ex,text align={left indent=1.112cm},text={|\PMstyle|D U S K~~~at latitude 62.0{°}N~~~(Sun 6{°} below horizon)}}]
plot[smooth,tension=0.5] coordinates{
(0.000, 10.982) (0.347, 11.067) (0.695, 11.170) (1.042, 11.287) (1.390, 11.417) 
(1.738, 11.555) (2.085, 11.699) (2.433, 11.848) (2.780, 11.999) (3.127, 12.152) 
(3.475, 12.306) (3.822, 12.461) (4.170, 12.616) (4.518, 12.771) (4.865, 12.927) 
(5.212, 13.085) (5.560, 13.244) (5.907, 13.406) (6.255, 13.572) (6.602, 13.741) 
(6.950, 13.915) (7.297, 14.096) (7.645, 14.283) (7.992, 14.478) (8.340, 14.683) 
(8.688, 14.898) (9.035, 15.126) (9.382, 15.371) (9.730, 15.641) (10.077, 15.958) 
(10.425, 16.477) };
```

The decorate code for 61.9°N works perfectly:

```
% decorate PM dusk with text aligned left
\path [decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=-2.4ex,text align={left indent=1.112cm},text={|\PMstyle|D U S K~~~at latitude 61.9{°}N~~~(Sun 6{°} below horizon)}}]
plot[smooth,tension=0.5] coordinates{
(0.000, 10.990) (0.347, 11.075) (0.695, 11.177) (1.042, 11.294) (1.390, 11.423) 
(1.738, 11.560) (2.085, 11.704) (2.433, 11.852) (2.780, 12.002) (3.127, 12.155) 
(3.475, 12.308) (3.822, 12.462) (4.170, 12.616) (4.518, 12.771) (4.865, 12.927) 
(5.212, 13.083) (5.560, 13.242) (5.907, 13.403) (6.255, 13.568) (6.602, 13.736) 
(6.950, 13.910) (7.297, 14.089) (7.645, 14.275) (7.992, 14.469) (8.340, 14.671) 
(8.688, 14.884) (9.035, 15.109) (9.382, 15.351) (9.730, 15.615) (10.077, 15.919) 
(10.425, 16.358) (10.494, 16.557) };
```

The decorate code for 62.1°N works perfectly:

```
% decorate PM dusk with text aligned left
\path [decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=-2.4ex,text align={left indent=1.112cm},text={|\PMstyle|D U S K~~~at latitude 62.1{°}N~~~(Sun 6{°} below horizon)}}]
plot[smooth,tension=0.5] coordinates{
(0.000, 10.973) (0.347, 11.059) (0.695, 11.162) (1.042, 11.280) (1.390, 11.410) 
(1.738, 11.549) (2.085, 11.694) (2.433, 11.843) (2.780, 11.996) (3.127, 12.149) 
(3.475, 12.304) (3.822, 12.459) (4.170, 12.615) (4.518, 12.771) (4.865, 12.928) 
(5.212, 13.086) (5.560, 13.247) (5.907, 13.409) (6.255, 13.576) (6.602, 13.746) 
(6.950, 13.921) (7.297, 14.103) (7.645, 14.291) (7.992, 14.488) (8.340, 14.694) 
(8.688, 14.911) (9.035, 15.142) (9.382, 15.392) (9.730, 15.668) (10.077, 16.000) 
(10.355, 16.415) };
```

And the original decorate code for 62.0°N **works correctly** if I use four decimal places for the coordinates:

```
% decorate PM dusk with text aligned left
\path [decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=-2.4ex,text align={left indent=1.112cm},text={|\PMstyle|D U S K~~~at latitude 62.0{°}N~~~(Sun 6{°} below horizon)}}]
plot[smooth,tension=0.5] coordinates{
(0.0000, 10.9816) (0.3475, 11.0669) (0.6950, 11.1698) (1.0425, 11.2874) (1.3900, 11.4165) 
(1.7375, 11.5546) (2.0850, 11.6990) (2.4325, 11.8476) (2.7800, 11.9990) (3.1275, 12.1519) 
(3.4750, 12.3061) (3.8225, 12.4608) (4.1700, 12.6158) (4.5175, 12.7712) (4.8650, 12.9272) 
(5.2125, 13.0847) (5.5600, 13.2442) (5.9075, 13.4064) (6.2550, 13.5718) (6.6025, 13.7411) 
(6.9500, 13.9154) (7.2975, 14.0958) (7.6450, 14.2830) (7.9925, 14.4784) (8.3400, 14.6828) 
(8.6875, 14.8979) (9.0350, 15.1259) (9.3825, 15.3709) (9.7300, 15.6410) (10.0775, 15.9582) 
(10.4250, 16.4775) };
```

For some reason I am unable to upload four test cases as ZIP files. The whole point of this report is that someone can verify the error and confirm that it is data-related. Please contact me so I can pass on the `.tex` files to someone to prove the issue I am experiencing.

**UPDATE #1:**

I have posted this issue in GitHub where I was able to upload the mentioned `.tex` files:

https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1297

Again ... this is an initial step in which I request that an expert can REPRODUCE my issue; agree that the error is INCORRECT and that this requires FURTHER INVESTIGATION and finally a FIX.

**UPDATE #2:**

Greetings David Carlisle! Grüß Gott Ulrike Fischer! Thanks Qrrbrbirbel. And thanks for all the support you gave me in the past. Apologies for posting an external link ... this was unintentional but I had forgotten you can't upload anything here.

I managed to whittle it down to a MWE (Minimum Working Example) as well as a MnWE (Minimum non-Working Example) *and* a Workaround (which I don't understand at all).

The MWE is here (and uses the 4 decimal places for the coordinates though **any** different coordinates would work just as well):

```
\pdfminorversion=4
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=5mm, bottom=5mm, left=2mm, right=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}               % for \draw  (load after 'graphicx')
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}   % to print text on a curve
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\PMstyle}{\sffamily\normalsize\color{blue}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% decorate PM dusk with text aligned left
\path [decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=-2.4ex,text align={left indent=1.112cm},text={|\PMstyle|D U S K~~~at latitude 62.0{°}N~~~(Sun 6{°} below horizon)}}]
plot[smooth,tension=0.5] coordinates{
(0.0000, 10.9816) (0.3475, 11.0669) (0.6950, 11.1698) (1.0425, 11.2874) (1.3900, 11.4165) 
(1.7375, 11.5546) (2.0850, 11.6990) (2.4325, 11.8476) (2.7800, 11.9990) (3.1275, 12.1519) 
(3.4750, 12.3061) (3.8225, 12.4608) (4.1700, 12.6158) (4.5175, 12.7712) (4.8650, 12.9272) 
(5.2125, 13.0847) (5.5600, 13.2442) (5.9075, 13.4064) (6.2550, 13.5718) (6.6025, 13.7411) 
(6.9500, 13.9154) (7.2975, 14.0958) (7.6450, 14.2830) (7.9925, 14.4784) (8.3400, 14.6828) 
(8.6875, 14.8979) (9.0350, 15.1259) (9.3825, 15.3709) (9.7300, 15.6410) (10.0775, 15.9582) 
(10.4250, 16.4775) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The MnWE that fails is here (and uses the coordinates with 3 decimal places that originally caused my `! Dimension too large.` error from a Ti*k*Z decorate path during `pdflatex <filename>.tex`):

```
\pdfminorversion=4
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=5mm, bottom=5mm, left=2mm, right=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}               % for \draw  (load after 'graphicx')
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}   % to print text on a curve
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\PMstyle}{\sffamily\normalsize\color{blue}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% decorate PM dusk with text aligned left
\path [decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=-2.4ex,text align={left indent=1.112cm},text={|\PMstyle|D U S K~~~at latitude 62.0{°}N~~~(Sun 6{°} below horizon)}}]
plot[smooth,tension=0.5] coordinates{
(0.000, 10.982) (0.347, 11.067) (0.695, 11.170) (1.042, 11.287) (1.390, 11.417) 
(1.738, 11.555) (2.085, 11.699) (2.433, 11.848) (2.780, 11.999) (3.127, 12.152) 
(3.475, 12.306) (3.822, 12.461) (4.170, 12.616) (4.518, 12.771) (4.865, 12.927) 
(5.212, 13.085) (5.560, 13.244) (5.907, 13.406) (6.255, 13.572) (6.602, 13.741) 
(6.950, 13.915) (7.297, 14.096) (7.645, 14.283) (7.992, 14.478) (8.340, 14.683) 
(8.688, 14.898) (9.035, 15.126) (9.382, 15.371) (9.730, 15.641) (10.077, 15.958) 
(10.425, 16.477) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and while I was working on the MnWE, I discovered that if you comment out the following line [corrected text follows] the error disappears!!! However the degree symbol is smaller as it is no longer a raised circle, i.e. less readable on a chart.

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}
```

I'm sure this will say something to you but it baffles me that a sensible `DeclareUnicodeCharacter` statement should result in an `! Dimension too large.` error, which is most confusing to the end user. I'm interested to hear your feedback ...... nevertheless I hope this is an error that can be fixed.

To be conform, I will also post the MnWE and the Workaround in Github.

**Workaround v2**: As it is impractical in my use-case to comment out the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}` line altogether, a better workaround is to replace `{°}` in the Decorate Path with `{\textdegree}` for the specific case (Mars 2020 at latitude 62°N) where the `! Dimension too large.` error message crashes PDF creation.

Comment: Your problem would be much more convenient to test if you would provide a small test document people can copy and paste.

Comment: you can not upload zip here, can you not make an example small enough to fit into a code block in your question? But in general arithemetic overflow is not necessarily a bug in the code, tex arithmetic is fixed point

Comment: the CPU or other hardware has no effect on the calculation, tex is not using hardware floating point: all arithmetic is exact integer arithmetic, scaled.

Comment: You could try `\pgfset{fpu/install only=veclen}` after loading the `fpu` library like I did in the answer [about decorating smooth plotted paths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700041). Otherweise, I request that you create a minimal working example.

Comment: oh well. As you already know which path is erronous you could easily make a small example of 20 lines instead of one with 1500 lines.  But beside this: tikz calculations are a bit fragile and some data can lead to too large values.

Comment: please do not use external links, make an example in the question,

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but if you add an extra pair of braces to make it `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}}` it seems to work. tikz decorate is known to be rather fickle with mathmode stuff.